# Bootstrap navbar doesn't work with Django template

Tags: django-templates, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a base HTML file in Django that pretty much is the one responsible for the rest of the pages to inherit a template but the navbar doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows if there is a known issue from Bootstrap or am I doing something horribly wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">BRAND</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
          <li class="navbar-link"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">


  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to Index</h1>
    <h2>This is index.html page showing!</h2>
  </div>



    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define _doesn't seem to work_? What is the problem?

Comment: You seem to be using classes from some old version of Bootstrap. Check the current docs for the right classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Hmm could question. sorry! Well actualy the navabar doesnt look formulated properly and it look more like a list rather than a typical static top navbar. you can check on codepen link below
https://codepen.io/ProD/pen/xYpdog

Comment: Thanks a lot @Klooven that seem to be the problem ;)

Comment: Good that it got resolved! Remember, the docs always provide up-to date information :)